# Laravel Forge Wildcard Let's Encrypt

Tags: laravel

I have an existing Laravel build using Forge and Digital Ocean.

I want to use Laravel Spark to allow me to take Stripe payments easily.

My understanding is that you cannot incorporate Spark in to an existing Laravel build so I was thinking to create another site on the same DO server using Forge and have it as a subdomain. mysite.com, sales.mysite.com

Now that Let's Encrypt can handle Wildcards where would I create the Let's Encrypt certificate? On the main site or the sub domain site?

Hope that makes sense? :-)

Thanks

Andy

Comment: [`*.example.com` does not match `example.com`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_certificate#Limitations). You would need to handle your sub-domain-less TLD specially. However, yes, having your merch-gate as a separate app on a separate domain is perfectly fine.